# Unable to save edits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I have a shape file i want to edit but i am not able to save the changes.
the shape file is a layer in geoserver(2.23.2) and loaded into QGIS(3.28.15) vis WFS 2.0.0 connection.

1. QGIS logs- Commit errors (warning): Could not commit changes to
   layer Kohir
2. QGIS logs- critical error- Layer Kohir : WFS service
   exception:
   {https://www.naturalearthdata.com}Kohir_Modified_Map is read-only
3. Geoserver logs- Couldn't replace original file with a temporary
   after a write operation. Because of:filepath/Kohir_Modified_Map.qix
   (Permission denied)

   java.io.IOException: Couldn't replace original file with a temporary
   after a write operation. Because of:
   filepath/Kohir_Modified_Map.qix (Permission denied)

I am using qgis on a windows system and geoserver is running on tomcat in a linux VM.

Note-

1. the file is in a azure container mounted to linux using blobfuse.
2. i am not able to edit this particular shapefile only, other are working fine.
3. i have tried downloading the file to my windows local system and directly load to QGIS instead via geoserver and i am able to save the edits.
4. i have no plugins installed.

How can i resolve this issue??

Comment: Hi, the shapefile is not open in any application, as for "windows has locked it because GeoServer has it open" i do not understand, do mean layer preview?
and is rastar data feasible in postgis and geopackage?

Comment: check user and rights access to your file on linux ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the linux reference - you need to give GeoServer write permission to the directory where the data is stored

Comment: @IanTurton are you referring to layer--->Security--->grant access to role? if so then i have given access for read and write to all roles for this layer.

Comment: Note- i have installed tomcat 9 and geoserver. I have run everything locally  and i am still getting same issue.

Comment: No, I'm talking about `chmod` permissions for the data folder for the user that runs GeoServer (`tomcat`?)